# Brackets in Access Query Using ConcatRelated Function

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm attempting to concatenate multiple records of field "dbo_race.racedesc" into one record based on username. I'm attempting to use the ConcatRelated function (http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html). As the username is text, I followed the article's example to include extra quotes.

The error I get is "Error 3126: Invalid bracketing of name '[dbo_indrace.username]'."

The error seems to be referring to the period within the brackets. However, if I only list the field without the table name, I am prompted that it could refer to more than one table listed in my FROM clause.

What would be the correct syntax for the ConcatRelated function?

```
SELECT DISTINCT dbo_ind.username, 
ConcatRelated("[racedesc]", "[dbo_race]", "[dbo_indrace.username] = """ & [dbo_ind.username] & """") AS racedescription
FROM dbo_race INNER JOIN (dbo_ind INNER JOIN dbo_indrace ON dbo_ind.username = dbo_indrace.username) ON dbo_race.race = dbo_indrace.race
WHERE dbo_race.lang='E';
```

Comment: does it give the same error if you do "[dbo_indrace].username = """ instead of "[dbo_indrace.username]"

Comment: Without brackets or with [dbo_indrace].username or [dbo_indrace].[username], I get "Error 3061: Too few parameters. Expected 1."

Answer (score 0):

Try changing [dbo_indrace.username] to [dbo_indrace].[username]

Same with [dbo_ind.username]

Comment: Without brackets or with [dbo_indrace].username or [dbo_indrace].[username], I get "Error 3061: Too few parameters. Expected 1.

Comment: That usually means you're trying to query against a table or field that doesn't exist.  Check your spelling and make sure the value formats are correct.